# Accessing rows not in focus in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, focus

I'm setting the style of unselected rows with Extended selection mode set up for my datagrid.  This works fine for rows that are on the screen, but as you scroll up or down, the rows not in focus are not adjusted.  I remember seeing some code somewhere to access unselected rows or even move the scroll position, but that seems like a broad sword approach.

Comment: Are you using code behind? Use a style in your xaml instead, it will be applied to every row.

Comment: I'm setting the style in code behind using a loop and I've confirmed every row is being updated. I tried setting the row style property of the data grid as well but that doesn't seem to apply to any of them

Comment: Use a style and datatrigger. The datagrid is virtualised. The rows which aren't visible don't exist.

Comment: You should include code where you set the style for each row and what have you tried in xaml. I am sure there is something that you have done/assumed that will cause grid not to apply the style. And we are here to pick up on that. So don't be shy and let us help you.

Comment: Thanks.  My solution is below

Answer (score 0):

After leveraging the advice from the community, I was able to get this working by assigning the RowStyle to the datagrid instead of each row individually.

```
private void SetDarkRowStyle()
{
     dgWaypoints.RowStyle = FindResource("DarkRowStyle") as Style;
}
```